# Insert a value changing shape in allocated vector fortran

Tags: arrays, performance, memory-management, fortran

I would like to ask you about a problem that I have frequently in the management of CSR/CSC* matrices using Fortran. 
Suppose we have a vector V with N real values. The vector has been allocated previously with a certain size. Now we have to add a value in the middle of it at the index P.
A brute force code would be:

```
allocate(tempV(N))
tempV=V
deallocate(V)
allocate(V(N+1))
V=(/tempV(1:P-1), newValue, tempV(P:N)/)
deallocate(tempV)
```

Clearly, if it is done once it is not a problem, but repeating it thousands times would not be so efficient. Memory would fill and empty 4 times every value I would like to insert.

I would like to know which would be a better procedure to tackle this problem. You can propose plain Fortran (preferred), but also some solution by libraries like MKL/Lapack/Blas.

**Addendum**: could I do it with RESHAPE? going through [this definition](http://www.nsc.liu.se/~boein/f77to90/a5.html#section17) (same of my Fortran-book definition), I could do something like

```
REAL, DIMENSION(1:1) :: newPad = (/ newValue /)
V=RESHAPE(V, (/ N+1 /), PAD=newPad)
```

Now the values has been added at the end of V, so I make a permutation with

V=(/ V(1:P-1), V(N+1:N+1), V(P:N) /)

In this way, it would avoid to create explicitly a temporary vector and to lose allocation.

Would it be efficient and scalable since RESHAPE could be parallelized already in the libraries?

---

***PS**: To make things clear CSR = Compressed Sparse Row format, CSC = Compressed Sparse Column format, more infos here:

*MKL definitions:*http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-9FCEB1C4-670D-4738-81D2-F378013412B0.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fortran 2003 subroutine `move_alloc` was introduced for this purpose. It moves the allocation status, array bounds, dynamic type, type parameters and values from the source to the target, without actually copying the data. The source variable becomes deallocated.

A modification of your code with a short example of `move_alloc` that requires only one copy operation:

```
allocate(tempV(N+1)) 
tempV(:P-1) = V(:P-1)
tempV(P)    = newValue
tempV(P+1:) = V(P:) 
call move_alloc(tempV, V)
```

Of course, doing this for multiple items at a time would reduce allocation overhead, but that may not be possible for you.

**Edit**
As for the recommendation of pointers if you cannot use any F2003 features, you could probably use a subroutine somewhat like this:

```
pure subroutine insert(arr, val, pos)
  real, pointer, intent(inout) :: arr(:)
  real, intent(in)             :: val
  integer, intent(in)          :: pos

  real, pointer :: temp(:)

  if(associated(arr)) then
    allocate(temp(lbound(arr,1):ubound(arr,1) + 1))
    ! ...or perhaps check/do something if pos is not within these bounds

    temp(:pos-1) = arr(:pos-1)
    temp(pos)    = val 
    temp(pos+1:) = arr(pos:)

    deallocate(arr)
    arr => temp
  endif
end subroutine insert
```

Of course you can easily adapt this to your purposes or make it more generic. You can use this with allocated pointer variables:

```
real, pointer :: V(:)
! :
allocate(V(10))
V = 1.
! :
call insert(V, 3.141592, 5)
```

Comment: I know that would sound silly, but does it confirm then that there is not such feature in Fortran9X as well as Fortran77? That's a real pity!

Comment: Indeed, they won't let you do this. But why is this a pity? It's a fairly trivial extension that I would think most compilers have implemented by now.

Comment: For clarity - "moves the allocation status (but not the contents)..." - allocation status is just a simple true/false concept (allocated/not allocated) - move_alloc transfers the value (and other characteristics, such as bounds, dynamic type, etc) across too.  I know you meant something like "the internal representation of the value in memory doesn't move" (typically - if from and to variables are not both targets it is not out of the question), but that's not how the answer reads.

Comment: @VladimirF in the case of pointer-list, what about the aligned memory buffer features? when allocating, Fortran is looking for a chunck of sequential memory on the heap/stack, isn't it? with pointer it would reduce performance in operations, right?

Comment: @IanH that is, only if you use a pointer representation you could be able to avoid copies because even move_alloc needs to spread out values along the vector.. right?

Comment: Why pointer list? I was talking about pointers to arrays. It is very similar to allocatables. `real,pointer :: A(:),B(:); allocate(A(10)); B=>A; nullify(A); deallocate(B)`  There are very minor performance penalties due to possible aliasing.

Comment: @IanH: I agree that was too terse; meant to say that (array) descriptors can be changed while the memory pointed to remains the same. Updated my answer.

Comment: @L.B.: Also added an example featuring array pointers. I would still only recommend this if you really cannot use any newer Fortran features.

Comment: One other aspect to consider for your first code snippet - if using F2003 and V is allocatable, the allocate statement for `tempV` is redundant (unless you want non-default lower bound), plus, in some respects, the `move_alloc` is redundant - if you are lazy then `V = [ V(:P-1), newValue, V(P:)]` is really all that is required.  However, current compilers are likely to implement that inefficiently, so if you are worried about performance, then your `move_alloc` is best, though for similar performance reasons it is best to avoid the array constructor (break it into three separate assignments).

Comment: @IanH: Thanks, just did a small test and was not aware that the difference was so pronounced, especially for allocatables. Is this just because a constructor can potentially contain complicating factors like nesting or implied do loops? I suppose I shall update that part too, since the question was asked with performance in mind.

Comment: Yes - things like that - the expression primary that is the structure constructor needs to be evaluated to completion before its value can be assigned or be used in an expression, etc - a simpler complication is if the constructor contained references to the value of tempV.  The easiest/safest way to handle this requirement is just to assemble the constructor in a separate area of memory in isolation from how/where it will be used and then if necessary copy the entire array to its final destination.  Here that copy would be totally redundant.  Compilers will get better at this with time!

Answer (score 1):

The question is really, whether you need the CSR format immediately after the insertion, or you can rather have more insertions first in a more insertion friendly format and convert then to CSR.

You may have a look at [sparskit](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/SPARSKIT/) and its linked list storage format, or you may create yourself some linked list for the new elements, and once you finished insertion, you could build up a new CSR formatted matrix, sparing a lot of reshuffling the data.