# Fortran 90/95 Pointers in Derived Type

Tags: pointers, fortran, derived-types

I have a derived type with a pointer to an array of a second derived type

```
TYPE vertex
   REAL :: x, y, z
END TYPE

TYPE path
   TYPE(vertex), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: vertices => NULL()
END TYPE
```

The intent is to make the vertices array resizable so that any number of vertex points can be added to the array. I have created code to append a vertex to that pointer.

```
SUBROUTINE path_append_vertex(this, x, y, z)
IMPLICIT NONE

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!  Variable declarations.
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE(path), INTENT(inout) :: this
REAL, INTENT(in)   :: x, y, z

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!  Local Variable declarations.
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INTEGER :: status
TYPE(vertex), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: vertices

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!  Start of executable code
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF (ASSOCIATED(this%vertices)) THEN
! Create a temporary array the same size as current number of vertices. Copy the
! contents of the old array to the new array then delete the old array.
   ALLOCATE(vertices(SIZE(this%vertices)), STAT = status)
   CALL check_status(status)
   vertices = this%vertices
   DEALLOCATE(this%vertices)

! Create a new array with one extra element. Copy the contents of the temporary
! array to the new one the delete the temporary array.
   ALLOCATE(this%vertices(SIZE(vertices) + 1), STAT = status)
   CALL check_status(status)
   this%vertices(1:SIZE(vertices)) = vertices
   DEALLOCATE(vertices)

   this%vertices(SIZE(this%vertices))%x = x
   this%vertices(SIZE(this%vertices))%y = y
   this%vertices(SIZE(this%vertices))%z = z
ELSE
   ALLOCATE(this%vertices(1), STAT = status)
   CALL check_status(status)

   this%vertices(1)%x = x
   this%vertices(1)%y = y
   this%vertices(1)%z = z
ENDIF

END SUBROUTINE
```

I create a few path objects.

```
TYPE ipch_desc
   ...
   TYPE(path) :: chordPath
END TYPE

SUBROUTINE ipch_desc_construct(this, ...)
...
TYPE (ipch_desc), INTENT(inout)          :: this
...
!  Must NULL out the vertices array or else it will point to the last
!  integration_path created in memory. Not sure why these are defaulting
!  to NULL
this%chordPath%vertices => NULL()

CALL path_append_vertex(this%chordPath, xcart_i(1), xcart_i(2), xcart_i(3))
CALL path_append_vertex(this%chordPath, xcart_f(1), xcart_f(2), xcart_f(3))

!  Check the value of the path vertices.
write(*,*) this%chordPath%vertices

END SUBROUTINE
```

Everything work all well and good and I get the correct values for each vertex. For instance for three path objects created I get

```
 -0.33808113528699218        1.0467574437103653       0.10713720000000000      -0.16057879084545851       0.49717960298733294       0.10713720000000000     
 -0.33322243268266594        1.0483142707971911       1.42240000000000010E-003 -0.14945358419461796       0.47017940500485894       1.42240000000000010E-003
 -0.33656460666251325        1.0472460386853264      -0.10629900000000000      -0.15821659220752302       0.49230280357365630      -0.10629900000000000
```

When using these path objects latter in the code,

```
SUBROUTINE ipch_mc_model_compute(a_ipch, ...)
...
TYPE (ipch_desc), INTENT (inout)     :: a_ipch
...
!  Check the value of the path vertices again.
write(*,*) a_ipch%chordPath%vertices
...
END SUBROUTINE
```

only the first N-1 values remain correct. For the same values created above I get,

```
 -0.33808113528699218        1.0467574437103653       0.10713720000000000      -0.16057879084545851       0.49717960298733294       0.10713720000000000     
 -0.33322243268266594        1.0483142707971911       1.42240000000000010E-003 -0.14945358419461796       0.47017940500485894       1.42240000000000010E-003
  0.15094203233057696       6.94277920927416864E-310 -0.10629900000000000       1.63041663127611360E-322  3.01884064661153912E-003  6.94277920927179713E-310
```

Regardless of the number of `path` objects I create, the Nth always ends up with wrong values. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where the problem was. The `ipch_desc` object was being constructed to a temp then assigned to an element in an array.

```
ipch_desc_arr(icount_chords) = ipch_desc_temp
```

I will either need to remove this temporary or over load the default assignment operators to fix it.

Comment: If you write you own answer, you should also probably accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct.   You could simplify it a bit.   Why have a derived type PATH to contain a single variable?   You could directly resize an array of type VERTEX without this additional type.  Also, I see no reason to use a pointer; allocatable would see to be sufficient.   Fortran 2003 provide MOVE_ALLOC, which would also provide a simplification (if this is available in the compiler that you are using) (see [Insert a value changing shape in allocated vector fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607020/insert-a-value-changing-shape-in-allocated-vector-fortran)).

```
module vertex_stuff

TYPE vertex
   REAL :: x, y, z
END TYPE

contains

SUBROUTINE path_append_vertex(this, x, y, z)
IMPLICIT NONE

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!  Variable declarations.
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TYPE(vertex), dimension (:), allocatable, INTENT(inout) :: this
REAL, INTENT(in)   :: x, y, z

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!  Local Variable declarations.
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

TYPE(vertex), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: tmp_vertices

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!  Start of executable code
!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF (allocated(this)) THEN
! Create a temporary array the same size as current number of vertices. Copy the
! contents of the old array to the new array then delete the old array.
   ALLOCATE(tmp_vertices(SIZE(this)))
   tmp_vertices = this
   DEALLOCATE(this)

! Create a new array with one extra element. Copy the contents of the temporary
! array to the new one the delete the temporary array.
   ALLOCATE(this(SIZE(tmp_vertices) + 1))
   this(1:SIZE(tmp_vertices)) = tmp_vertices
   DEALLOCATE(tmp_vertices)

   this(SIZE(this))%x = x
   this(SIZE(this))%y = y
   this(SIZE(this))%z = z
ELSE
   ALLOCATE(this(1))

   this(1)%x = x
   this(1)%y = y
   this(1)%z = z
ENDIF

END SUBROUTINE


SUBROUTINE output_vertices (this)
IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE(vertex), dimension (:), INTENT(in) :: this
integer :: i

write (*, '(// "Current vertices:" )' )

do i=1, size(this)
   write (*, '( 3F5.2 )' ) this (i) % x, this (i) % y, this (i) % z
end do

end SUBROUTINE output_vertices

end module vertex_stuff


program vertices

use vertex_stuff

implicit none

TYPE (vertex), dimension (:), allocatable :: this

call path_append_vertex(this, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2)
call output_vertices (this)

call path_append_vertex(this, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2)
call output_vertices (this)

call path_append_vertex(this, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2)
call output_vertices (this)

call path_append_vertex(this, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2)
call output_vertices (this)

call path_append_vertex(this, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2)
call output_vertices (this)

end program vertices
```